# How to make HTML code as readable in PHP

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want to show **`<li> </li>`** in at my php page. But when i am writing this code i am getting HTML ourput as List tag. But i want to show the example code as **`<li>This is first line </li>`** there

How can i show that. I know that there need to use \ to make any code readable is PHP. So i used,
 **`\<li>This is first line </li>\`** But i did not get proper result which i want.

Anyone can help by sharing that code?

Comment: See [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

Comment: Post the complete PHP code, and then also paste the generated HTML code from `view-source`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like

```
&lt;li&gt; This is first line &lt;/li&gt;
```

Either you can use `htmlentities` like

```
echo htmlentities('<li>This is first line </li>');
```

Comment: Who have down it...please tell me the reasn

Comment: my guess would be, some1 prolly did cuz u edited after i posted and Boaz commented ;p

Comment: Actually Iam writing comment to ask for the reason to downvote.In that time you answred it.So me also stoped that and put it in ans...

Comment: I didn't really get what you said, can you write your comment again?

Answer (score 4):

Check function [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).

```
$str = "A 'quote' is <b>bold</b>";

// Outputs: A 'quote' is &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;
echo htmlentities($str);

// Outputs: A &#039;quote&#039; is &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;
echo htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES);
```